# Scroll can't move after hide and show using jquery

Tags: jquery

Cant able to scroll the window scroll when i hide and show the scroll bar using jquery. So when i click a button i used to call method

```
$('html,body').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
```

and when i toggle the button i call this function

```
$('html,body').css({'overflow':'auto'});
```

Its working fine but cant able to scroll.

Comment: Sure, the `overflow: hidden` function is not to hide scrollbars, but _hide_ all content outside the current viewport.

Comment: can you put jfiddal to your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `,` instead of `:` and no `{ }` needed inside `.css`

```
$('html,body').css('overflow','hidden');
```

and same in case while auto

```
$('html,body').css('overflow','auto');
```

Take a simple **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/mg3fr1dd/)**

Comment: Both can be used..both refects the same result.
{} is used if you need to add more properties.
$('body').css({'height':'50px','width':'50px'});

Comment: I said its not needed here if it is the only thing he is setting!! I havent said its not correct!! Read the answer properly please!! @Jayababu. and I know the fact that its needed to add more properties!!

Comment: It wont solve his problem right?so better you might have posted as a comment not as a answer.

Comment: Its working .wonder..but what difference it made, if we keep like this technically? thanks learnt a new thing today.

Comment: Anytime!! I thought demo wasn't required here! But, yea needs sometimes to prove our answer! Anyways!! Happy coding..